# Dynamically binding Drop Down List in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu, entity

I trying to create a drop down list and bind it to the values fetched from database.
 How can I do this. I have done following till now. I want the value of the items of the dropdown ie c.ID in following code to be bind with the Currency_ID of the CountryVM.

```
 public CountryVM()
    {      
            [DisplayName("Country ID")]
            [Required]
            public string ID { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DisplayName("Description")]
            public string Description { get; set; }


            [DisplayName("Currency Id")]
            public Nullable<int> Currency_ID { get; set; }

        }
```

//Controller

```
   DAL library = new DAL();
   var items = library.GetAllCurrency(Library.Filter.CURRENCY_SYMBOL);
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = items.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.CURRENCY_SYMBOL, Value = c.ID.ToString() });

    ViewBag.curr_symbol = list;
    return View();
```

//In View  I am trying to access my DropDown as follows :

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Currency_ID,"curr_symbol" )// how to write this.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this in view:

```
@
{
SelectList CurrencyList = (SelectList)ViewBag.curr_symbol;
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Currency_ID,CurrencyList)
```

and in action:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = items.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.CURRENCY_SYMBOL, Value = c.ID.ToString() }).ToList();
```

or:

```
var list = (from c in items
           select new SelectListItem {Text = c.CURRENCY_SYMBOL, 
                                      Value = c.ID.ToString() }).ToList();
```

**Update:**

As you told in discussion that it is throwing exception on form post so what you need is to fill the List again and put it in `ViewBag` in post action as from `ViewBag` it is removed.

Comment: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Currency_ID'. <= I am getting this error

Comment: make sure that list has elements and its being Set in ViewBag

Comment: edit the post with what you did change in action and View, then i can help you much easuly

Comment: I just wrote :  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CurrencyList = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.curr_symbol; in my view

Comment: did you tried the way i posted, i use to do this way  and it works fine, check in action your setting viewbag selectlist has items

Comment: i have seen but make sure by putting breakpoint what is coming in list, whats the count

Comment: No the list is displaying fine but When I submit the form the exception occurs

Comment: ohh,, ok you need to fill it again and put it in ViewBag in post action, ViewBag becomes null when action is called

Comment: you put value in viewbag from action and use it in view when another action is called it is again back null

Comment: Ohh ok I did not knew that. Hey can you suggest me some good books on MVC 4. I am tired of working this way!

Comment: asp.net mvc 4 in action, pro asp.net mvc 4

Comment: Thanks for the help and book suggestions!

Comment: @Ehsan i have doubt why you are casting again in view for viewbag.viewbag is dynamic right ? why we do need to cast ? whether it will throw any error if we not casting to SelectList ?

Comment: @SivaRajini: You do not need to cast ViewBag